# Show that if $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}x_k=0$ then $| \sum_{k=1}^{k=2n} kx_k| \leq n^2$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1,...,x_{2n} \in [-1,1]$. Show that if $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}x_k=0$ then $$| \sum_{k=1}^{2n} kx_k| \leq n^2$$

I've tried to use the following formula:
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^{2n}kx_k = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \sum_{j=k}^{2n} x_j 
$$
But I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any real number $a$ is
$$
\left |\sum_{k=1}^{2n} kx_k \right| 
= \left |\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (k-a)x_k \right| \le \sum_{k=1}^{2n} |k-a| \, .
$$
As it turns out, choosing any $a$ in the interval $[n, n+1]$ gives the desired estimate:
$$
\left |\sum_{k=1}^{2n} kx_k \right|  \le \sum_{k=1}^n \left( a - k\right) + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \left( k - a\right) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} k - \sum_{k=1}^n k  = n^2 \, .
$$

The bound is sharp, equality holds if $x_1 = \ldots = x_n = -1$ and  $x_{n+1} = \ldots = x_{2n} = +1$.

*Remark:* For an *odd* number of real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_{2n+1} \in [-1, 1|$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}x_k=0$ the same method gives the (sharp) bound
$$
 \left |\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} kx_k \right| \le n(n+1) \, ,
$$
here one has to choose $a=n+1$.

Comment: Why does it suffice to consider $y_k\in\{-1,1\}$ where the statement is $y_k\in[-1,1]$?

Comment: @FShrike: Oops, I misread $x_1,...,x_{2n} \in [-1,1]$ as $x_1,...,x_{2n} \in \{-1,1 \}$ ! – I'll see if I can fix the answer, or otherwise delete it.

Comment: @FShrike: I have rewritten the answer, hopefully it is correct now!

Comment: why not taking a = n ?  I think it will do the job

Comment: @user47204: You are right, any $a$ between $n$ and $n+1$ does the job. For symmetry reasons, $a=n+1/2$ was the first thing I tried, and it worked.

Comment: Very nice +1 ${}$